# Get element by class not ID to effect multiple items (HTML Canvas Graphs)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using PHP to create a `foreach` loop for stats using HTML5 Canvas. Now everything is working great except the JavaSscript I found to create the Canvas Graph, it gets an element by `id` and so only manually targets one item, not sure how I can change up this code to target any amount of items created by the PhP `foreach` loop.

Here is the JavaScript I found along with the HTML element (ignore the PhP variables in the data-attributes, they are returning data):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('graph'); // get canvas
        //var el = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");

        var options = {
            percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
            color: el.getAttribute('data-color') || 0,
            size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 90,
            lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 3,
            rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
        }

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

        if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
            G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

        el.appendChild(span);
        el.appendChild(canvas);

        ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
        ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

        //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
        var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

        var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
            percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
                ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
            ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
            ctx.stroke();
        };

        drawCircle('#eeeeee', 1, 100 / 100);
        drawCircle(options.color, options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="graph" data-percent="<?php echo $percentage; ?>" data-color="<?php echo $color; ?>" style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>;"></div>
```

using get element by class name returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: el.getAttribute is not a function

Comment: So what is the problem? `document.getElementsByClassName("chart");` should return an array of all elements with the class 'chart'

Comment: I added that, it doesnt, it returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: el.getAttribute is not a function

Comment: @PiecesofEight it returns an array of elements. Not the same as returning a single element when you use the ID. You'll have to loop through the array and do what you're doing to each element on that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList object. What you need to do is turn it into an array and loop over all it's elements and execute your code for each of them. Here is a minimally-changed version of how your code should work:

```js
// Get all the elements with 'chart' class as a NodeList object
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");

// Turn the NodeList into an array
elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);

// Loop over all the elements
elements.forEach(function (el) {
  var options = {
    percent:  el.getAttribute('data-percent') || 25,
    color: el.getAttribute('data-color') || 0,
    size: el.getAttribute('data-size') || 90,
    lineWidth: el.getAttribute('data-line') || 3,
    rotate: el.getAttribute('data-rotate') || 0
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = options.percent + '%';

  if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager) !== 'undefined') {
    G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
  }

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = canvas.height = options.size;

  el.appendChild(span);
  el.appendChild(canvas);

  ctx.translate(options.size / 2, options.size / 2); // change center
  ctx.rotate((-1 / 2 + options.rotate / 180) * Math.PI); // rotate -90 deg

  //imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);
  var radius = (options.size - options.lineWidth) / 2;

  var drawCircle = function(color, lineWidth, percent) {
    percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, percent || 1), 1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round'; // butt, round or square
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth
      ctx.stroke();
  };

  drawCircle('#eeeeee', 1, 100 / 100);
  drawCircle(options.color, options.lineWidth, options.percent / 100);
});
```

```html
<div class="chart" data-percent="100" data-color="red" style="color: red;"></div>
<div class="chart" data-percent="30" data-color="red" style="color: red;"></div>
```

However, this code should definitely be refactored. For instance, there is no point in declaring `drawCircle` function on every iteration.

Also read up on [getElementByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp), and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Thanks you!! You are a life saver, will read into those article links, thanks!